# Is there a way to validate time using Moment JS?

Tags: momentjs

Is there a way to validate if the String passed as time is valid using Moment JS?

The operations `moment("2014-12-13 asdasd","YYYY-MM-DD LT").isValid()` or `moment("asdasd","LT").isValid()` equate to `true` which ideally shouldn't happen.

My application uses multiple languages and it is really not possible for me to come up with a RegEx pattern to validate the string. For example, if I get the time string as `"午前12時12分0秒"`, Moment JS should be able to validate this. I checked the source and found that time checking is not that strict in the library. I might have missed something. Please help.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As described [in the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), as of moment 2.3.0, you can pass a third parameter `true` which turns on "strict parsing" mode.

```
moment("2014-12-13 asdasd","YYYY-MM-DD LT", true).isValid()   // false

moment("2014-12-13 12:34 PM","YYYY-MM-DD LT", true).isValid()   // true
```

The down side is that it must match the locale's format (i.e. the one supplied as the second argument) *exactly*.  Since `LT` is equivalent to `h:mm A` in English, it will only accept 12-hour time without seconds.  If you pass 24 hour time, or pass seconds, then it will fail.

```
moment("2014-12-13 12:34:00 PM","YYYY-MM-DD LT", true).isValid()   // false
moment("2014-12-13 15:00","YYYY-MM-DD LT", true).isValid()         // false
```

A better solution might be to pass multiple formats with strict parsing:

```
var formats = ["YYYY-MM-DD LT","YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss A","YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss","YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"];
moment("2014-12-13 12:34 PM", formats, true).isValid()     // true
moment("2014-12-13 15:00", formats, true).isValid()        // true
moment("2014-12-13 12:34:00 PM", formats, true).isValid()  // true
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I plan on using moment()._lang._longDateFormat.LT to validate the string, which would change along with locales and should work fine.

Comment: If you're using a current version (2.2.0+), try this instead: `moment.localeData().longDateFormat('LT')`.  [docs here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/)

Comment: How can I validate date with zone abbr like '2014-12-13 12:34 PM PST', the format 'YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss A z' didn't work here

Answer (score 4):

```js
const allPossibleFormats = [
  'D MMMM YYYY',
  'D MMMM YYYY HH:mm',
  'DD-MM-YY',
  'DD-MM-YYYY',
  'DD.MM.YYYY',
  'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm',
  'DD/MM/YY',
  'DD/MM/YYYY',
  'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss',
  'HH:mm:ss',
  'M/D/YYYY',
  'D/M/YYYY',
  'MM-DD-YY',
  'MM-DD-YYYY',
  'MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss',
  'MM/DD/YY',
  'MM/DD/YYYY',
  'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss',
  'MMM D YYYY',
  'MMM D YYYY LT',
  'MMMM Do YYYY',
  'MMMM Do YYYY LT',
  'YYYY-DD-MM HH:mm:ss',
  'YYYY-MM',
  'YYYY-MM-DD',
  'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
  'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
  'YYYY-MM-DD LT',
  'YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss A',
  'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ',
  'ddd, MMM D YYYY LT',
  'dddd D MMMM YYYY HH:mm',
  'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY LT'
];

moment('Chicago Illinois 46702', allPossibleFormats, true).isValid(); // false
moment('18/01/1944', allPossibleFormats, true).isValid(); // true
moment('22-10-2020', allPossibleFormats, true).isValid(); // true
moment('1944-01-18 12:00:00', allPossibleFormats, true).isValid(); // true
moment('2001-01-01 00:00:00', allPossibleFormats, true).isValid(); // true
moment('2001-01', allPossibleFormats, true).isValid(); // true
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```