# Validate a non existing date with moment js

Tags: salesforce, momentjs

Good day to everyone.

I need to validate a non-existing date with moment taking the value from a datepicker, so far I couldn't do it. For example:

```
moment('29/02/2021').isValid()
```

will return `true` as the format is correct but the `date` as is does not exist... The point with this is to show to the user an error message whenever the value passed to the datepicker is an invalid `date` or whatever else that is not a `date` (`123456789` or `asd` for example)

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: `moment('29/02/2021').isValid()` output is `false`. Moreover, since you input is not ISO 8601 you should specify format when [parsing](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) and you can also use [strict mode](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/) if needed. Have a look at momentjs docs and to related question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26040397/4131048) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24392357/4131048) to find working sample.

Comment: Thanks for reading my question, but I must say that the output is `true` and not `false`. I did my tests using the `console.log()` function and it returns true every time. I've read the momentjs docs and it says that will check first if the `date` has some predefined formats and in the end it will return a new `Date` instance instead. If you check that when parsing an invalid `date` it will take the closest `date` possible, in this case it will take `01/03/2021` (March 1st)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was pretty simple in the end. Adding the `'L'` parameter to the `moment` date constructor was enough to check if the incoming `date` exists or not.

Now if you do `moment('29/02/2021', 'L').isValid()` will return false instead of true, this also checks for the user's `locale` and will apply the corresponding format.